# How to use firebase auth with electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I have firebase project the works fine with android and web(js).
Now I start to work with Electron and I try to use Google sign-in using firebase lib.
Every time that I try to login I get same Exception:

"{code: "auth/wrong-password", message: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.", a: null}".

Here is my code:

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXX"            
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("Email","password").then((result)=>{
    console.log("result", result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    // Here I get the error
})
```